# using .hasClass to target multiple classes

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to see if a form does not contain either class. It works fine if I only look for one, but if I add multiple classes to the `if` statement, it seems to bypass them.

```
if (!form.hasClass('no-ajax') || !form.hasClass('register-step')) {
```

HTML:

```
<form id="basic-info-form" class="register-step form efocus" method="post" action="form_process.php?source=newUser">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your if statement. You are saying if the form does NOT have class no-ajax OR has class register-step. So if any of the conditions is true it will go into your if-statement.

you want to make sure it has neither class so it should be && instead of ||

Answer (score 0):

can you try like

```
var className = $('.myclass').attr('class');
 if(className.indexOf('myclasscheck') > = 0)
```